# What is the name of such sentence in English syntax? (Pronoun + auxiliary verb + noun / adjective)

Tags: grammar, syntax, lexical-verbs

What is the name of such sentence in English syntax?

> ***Pronoun + auxiliary verb (or lexical verb) + noun / adjective***

No verb in the sentence.

for example:

> I am a student

or

> I am shy

I want to describe such kind of sentences by the conventional (and also shortest) terminology

Comment: I think, given that you fail to recognize the generic "to be" verb as the main verb of these sentences, you're better off working to perfect your **basic** English grammar, and forgetting about esoteric grammar classification.  Only a very few native speakers know what a "copula sentence" is, and even fewer care.

Comment: @Andrew Auxiliary verb has 4 groups which one of them is "to be"... See here for example: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DZ4qfum5dW8/maxresdefault.jpg and also here: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=auxiliary+verb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiml_Xmg9fXAhXoQpoKHemJAO8Q_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662#imgrc=eJ5VxPQWzrIW_M:

Comment: Sure, but three of these can be simple verbs.  *I **am** a Star Wars fan. I **do** laundry on Fridays.  I **have** a pet cat.*    My point is that, instead of worrying about what (mostly) useless English grammar terms, you learn how to **speak, read, and write English** like a native.

Comment: I've got the answer out of this site and I'll put it here for others. The name of such sentence is: nominal sentence (because it doesn't contain verbs but nouns https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_sentence and see also here: http://slideplayer.info/slide/2763962/10/images/1/Nominal+and+Verbal+Sentences.jpg

Comment: Your examples are not nominal sentences.  The Wikipedia article gives clear examples, none of which apply here.  James K answered your question -- but, of course, it's up to you whether you accept the advice of native speakers or imagine that you somehow know better.  As the old English saying goes, *"You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink"*

Comment: @Andrew If you don't know or care about the grammar, you are free to pass on answering the question.  It doesn't mean the OP can't or shouldn't ask.  It's not at all esoteric.

Comment: @COX1 Your two sources on "nominal sentence" contradict each other.  The Wikipedia article says that "Jones winner" is a nominal sentence and contrasts it with "Jones is the winner" (strongly implying that the latter isn't a nominal sentence). The WP article says "The omission of the verb 'to be' can also provide basis for nominal sentences", again implying that it's non-nominal if "be" is present.  You and your second source, by contrast, say it's nominal even if "be" is present.  But it's unclear whether your second source is authoritative.

Comment: I see something different in wiki there, and let me cite it: *"They can also be found in newspaper headlines, such as "Jones Winner" where the intended meaning is with the copular verb, "Jones is the Winner""*. Then wikipedia doesn't say that " "Jones winner" is a nominal sentence and contrasts it with "Jones is the winner" " but it says that sometimes newspapers use "Jones Winner" where the intended meaning is "Jones is the Winner""*. It is not new for me as ELL and of course for you as an English native speaker. Moreover, the rest examples there from some languages that I speak, prove that.

Answer (score 3):

That is not an auxiliary verb. The verb "am" is the main verb.

The verb "to be" **can** be an auxiliary verb. But it can also be a main verb.

Auxillary verbs work with another verb. Eg "I *am* playing tennis." "I *have* eaten chips."  The words "am" and "have are auxiliary to the words "playing" or "eaten", forming the present continuous and perfect tenses respectively

There is no other verb in "I am shy", the verb "am" is the main verb.

In these sentences it is linking the subject (I) with a subject-complement (the adjective "shy", or the noun "a student") when a verb is used to link like this it is a "copula".

So the structure is pronoun-copula-complement, and you could call these "copula sentences".

Comment: **It is** an auxiliary verb. Auxiliary verb has 4 groups which one of them is "to be". See here for example: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DZ4qfum5dW8/maxresdefault.jpg and here: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=auxiliary+verb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiml_Xmg9fXAhXoQpoKHemJAO8Q_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662#imgrc=eJ5VxPQWzrIW_M:

Comment: In the sentence "I am shy" the word "am" is not an auxiliary verb.  In the sentence "I am playing tennis" the word "am" is an auxiliary verb.  So the verb "to be" is sometimes an auxiliary verb, and sometimes not an auxiliary verb. All the other verbs in your image are sometimes auxiliary verbs and sometimes main verbs

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't find any source for this differentiation between "auxiliary verb - to be" to simply "to be" (without auxiliary verb), but I found opposite since "to be" apparently *always* categorized under auxiliary verb, or alternatively there are mistakes in the following  books as follow (in the next comment I'll put the link to the books). In the meantime I can say that the answer for my question (what is such kind of sentence^ called in grammar) is: **"nominal sentence"** or **"equational sentence"**

Comment: Right, it's not really debatable – it passes all the auxiliary tests, like participating in subject–auxiliary inversion ( *I am shy* → *Am I shy?*), so it's clearly an auxiliary.  Traditional grammar is simply wrong about this.

Comment: **nominal sentence**  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_sentence and see also here: http://slideplayer.info/slide/2763962/10/images/1/Nominal+and+Verbal+Sentences.jpg.

Comment: **equational sentence**: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Hq3Ig9x4iQkC&pg=PA176&dq=%22nominal+sentences%22+%22auxiliary+verb%22+%22TO+BE%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ1YHwtdjXAhUKGZoKHUcCDX8Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22nominal%20sentences%22%20%22auxiliary%20verb%22%20%22TO%20BE%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=hLYXL92GgwIC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=%22equational+sentences%22+%22auxiliary+verb%22+%22TO+BE%22&source=bl&ots=M8PtwjGvl5&sig=YwwwS0k2B6nHqXbVJlwPjulletE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia-L-AtNjXAhWnHJoKHYddBOYQ6AEIPjAC#v=onepage&q=%22equational%20sentences%22%20%22auxiliary%20verb%22%20%22TO%20BE%22&f=false

Comment: I prefer James K's more traditional definition of an auxiliary verb, but I was wrong to say there was no debate on the subject.  However, even Huddleston and Pullum admit that this kind of use of "be" is "non-core", and they define "non-core" as those usages which don't "satisfy the general definition of auxiliary verb".  So we have a usage of "be" which doesn't meet the definition of an auxiliary, and some people call it auxiliary regardless.

Comment: Yet even Huddleston and Pullum admit that "have" is sometimes a full lexical verb.  So COX1's source ( https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DZ4qfum5dW8/maxresdefault.jpg ) can't be used as evidence that those verbs are auxiliaries and only auxiliaries.  Not to mention the fact that the said source misspells "modal" as "model"!

Comment: @rjpond Yep!  This one is clearly an auxiliary, but *be* can also be lexical.  The claim that *be* is always an auxiliary is certainly false.  For more information, please see: [The Two *be*'s of English](http://pages.uoregon.edu/tpayne/UEG/UEG-additionalreading-ch11-2bes.pdf) by Thomas Payne.

Comment: Great reference! Thank you very much! I can learn from it that it is a lexical verb rather than an auxiliary verb. Maybe this books (as many internet sources) are incorrect. Isn't it?

Answer (score -2):

Such kind of sentence is called in the linguistic terminology: "**[nominal sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_sentence)**" or 
"**[equational sentence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nominal%20sentence)**" meaning that this sentence doesn't have a verbal predicate. Therefore, the opposite term is "verbal sentence" which has a verbal predicate.

> "Nominal sentence (also: equational sentence) is a linguistic term
>   that refers to a nonverbal sentence (i.e. a sentence without a finite
>   verb). As a nominal sentence **does not have a verbal predicate**, it
>   may contain a nominal predicate, an adjectival predicate, an adverbial
>   predicate or even a prepositional predicate." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_sentence))

This is not debatable definition for the *sentence* "I am shy" or others like it.

---

Regarding to definition of the sentence "I am shy" as a structure of:

> Pronoun + **auxiliary verb** + noun / adjective

based on some sources which are linked in the comments here, it is debatable. Others definite "am" in this sentence as **lexical verb** or **[copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics))** rather than an auxiliary verb.

**

Read also here:

- [The Two be's of English](http://pages.uoregon.edu/tpayne/UEG/UEG-additionalreading-ch11-2bes.pdf)
- [nominal sentence has an auxiliary verb "to be"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Hq3Ig9x4iQkC&pg=PA176&dq=%22nominal%20sentences%22%20%22auxiliary%20verb%22%20%22TO%20BE%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ1YHwtdjXAhUKGZoKHUcCDX8Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22nominal%20sentences%22%20%22auxiliary%20verb%22%20%22TO%20BE%22&f=false).
- [nominal sentence has an auxiliary verb "to be" (reference No. 2)](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=hLYXL92GgwIC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=%22equational%20sentences%22%20%22auxiliary%20verb%22%20%22TO%20BE%22&source=bl&ots=M8PtwjGvl5&sig=YwwwS0k2B6nHqXbVJlwPjulletE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia-L-AtNjXAhWnHJoKHYddBOYQ6AEIPjAC#v=onepage&q=%22equational%20sentences%22%20%22auxiliary%20verb%22%20%22TO%20BE%22&f=false)